# excel match one with many values

Tags: excel

I have data to reconcile between two system. one system might reported value 100 but on another system 50 two times.I need to consider them as possible match.
But not every record will have possible match

```
Column A   Column B
SAP system Local system
100.00          50.00
435.00          50.00
146.25          435.00
53.75           253.50
```

I should conclude 100 has matching data (50 & 50) & 435 has matching data.I can match the exact one with formula but is there a way to match combination of values like 100.00 case?

Comment: Are the matching values consecutive and can there be more than two of them?

Comment: Hi Tom, it cant be consecutive but will be two only

Comment: So if column B contained 50,435,50,253 would the two 50's still match? What if it was 25,75,435,253?

Comment: any of the combination of values should match with column A value. If column B has 25, 75 then its a match as well. The other exact matches 435 has exact match, 253 doesnt have any match...

Answer (score 0):

This function will find the first matching pair and return the positions of the matching numbers in column B, called as:-

```
=FindPair(A2,B2:B5)



Option Explicit

Function FindPair(TotVal As Range, SearchVals As Range) As String

Dim Tot As Integer, i As Long, j As Long, length As Long, SearchVal As Double, found As Boolean
Dim store() As Double
Dim sum As Double

length = SearchVals.Rows.Count

ReDim store(length)
SearchVal = TotVal.Cells(1, 1).Value

For i = 1 To length
    store(i) = SearchVals(i)
Next i

found = False
FindPair = ""
For i = 1 To length - 1
    sum = store(i)
    For j = i + 1 To length
        If (sum + store(j)) = SearchVal Then
            found = True
            GoTo finish
        End If
    Next j
Next i

finish:
If found Then
   FindPair = CStr(i) & "," & CStr(j)
End If

End Function
```